# ASP.NET Core 6.0 / Razor pages / add info about currently logged in user to the Session

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0, httpsession

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app using Razor pages. For authentication, I'm using the MS Identity subsystem / OpenID Connect, with Azure Active Directory as my identity provider. This all works quite nicely - users are asked to provide their usual credentials, and in the course of the app, I can always get the `HttpContext.User` claims principal and inspect whatever I need about the currently logged on user.

What I would like to do is store some information (e.g. the user-principal name claim's value of the logged in user) into the ASP.NET Core session state (because I need to access this in places where I do not have access to the `HttpContext.User` property).

I was looking at writing some type of a **filter** to do this - only to discover that neither action filters, nor endpoint filters (in ASP.NET Core 7.0), are [supported in Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ;-(

OK - so that leaves me with the challenge of *when* exactly I can put that information into session. Is there some "hook" I can tap into that is called upon successful authentication of a user? Or is there any other "global" location where I could tap into the `HttpContext.User` property and extract the value from the `userPrincipalName` claim?

Do I need to create a separate base class derived from `PageModel`, that I can then use as the base class for all my specific Razor page models? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: If wanna do some actions after authorization, Maybe middleware is more suitable than filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly the approach would be to register a custom middleware after the calls to auth and `UseSession`:

```cs
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

// ...

app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    if (ctx.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        // ctx.Session.Set(...);
    }
    await next();
});

// ...

app.MapRazorPages();
```

Comment: Thanks - very simple and "approachable" - and it works like a charm, thank you so much